# FloatingActionButton onLongPress listener in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I need to have a secondary action to be performed during the long press of my `FloatingActionButton` in my app.

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: someFunction,
  child: Icon(Icons.add),
  onLongPressed: //Something like this or any other solution
),
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd suggest to use `InkWell` so that you can also have ripple effect.

Here is how you can use it.

```
floatingActionButton: InkWell(
  splashColor: Colors.blue,
  onLongPress: () {
    // handle your long press functionality here
  },
  child: FloatingActionButton(
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
    onPressed: someFunction,
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thank you @CopsOnRoad. This seems simple and paved my path to find the one I posted below. The only difference is that your solution is showing the ripple effect for a square shape, not for the circle of the FAB. Thank you!

Comment: @MubarakZade Thanks, for that effect you can wrap `InkWell` in `ClipOval`.

Answer (score 3):

There does exist an onLongPress gesture that can be used with GestureDetector. There is not a similar direct solution like this with FloatingActionButton.

But if you want to use a FloatingActionButton and not only a GestureDetector then you can easily nest the FAB in the GestureDetector like this to achieve the same results:

```
GestureDetector(
  onLongPress: () {
    print("Long press made");
  },
  child: FloatingActionButton(
    child: Text("FAB"),
    onPressed: () {},
  ),
)
```

You can read more about onLongPress in Flutter's official docs [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/gestures)

Comment: I like this solution. It's more intuitive than `InkWell`, as `GestureDetector` exists for the purpose of detecting gestures :) The only difference I can see is that `InkWell` (used without `splashColor`) gives you haptic feedback by default.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own LongPressFloatingActionButton, because the StatefullWidget already has this option.

See at:
 [Flutter - I want to select the card by onLongPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50462281/flutter-i-want-to-select-the-card-by-onlongpress)

Api:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/WidgetController/longPress.html

Inside the state of your new CustomStatefullWidget that wraps the FloatingActionButton you use it like:

```
class CustomWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;
  final bool longPressEnabled;
  final VoidCallback callback;

  const CustomWidget({Key key, this.index, this.longPressEnabled, this.callback}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomWidgetState createState() => new _CustomWidgetState();
}

class _CustomWidgetState extends State<CustomWidget> {
  bool selected = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new GestureDetector(
      onLongPress: () {
        setState(() {
          selected = !selected;
        });
        widget.callback();
      },
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the solutions I got above, I created my own one which seems to be having the desired ripple effect as well. Thank you all.

```
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
       onPressed: normalPressAction,
       child: GestureDetector(
       child: Icon(Icons.add),
          onLongPress: longPressAction,
          ),
    ),
```

Comment: But won't it will limit the gesture detection to the icon only instead of the whole button, I think the solution above achieves the desired result in a slightly better way.

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me.